# Title page in elsarticle class with corresponding author information as footnote

Tags: titles, elsarticle

I want to use elsarticle for my paper but the journal requires a title page with corresponding author information as a footnote. I managed to add the title page by changing following lines in the `elsarticle.cls`

```
\long\def\MaketitleBox{%
\resetTitleCounters
\def\baselinestretch{1}%
\begin{center}%
\def\baselinestretch{1}%
\Large\@title\par\vskip18pt
\normalsize\elsauthors\par\vskip10pt
\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt
%\hrule\vskip12pt
%\ifvoid\absbox\else\unvbox\absbox\par\vskip10pt\fi
\ifvoid\absbox\else\clearpage\unvbox\absbox\par\vskip30pt\fi
\ifvoid\keybox\else\unvbox\keybox\par\vskip10pt\fi
%\hrule\vskip12pt
\end{center}%
}
```

but I can not bring the footnote to the title page and it goes after the abstract (2nd page). Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you been asked by the journal to use class `elsarticle`? If yes, do not change the layout, and please never do change an original class. If no, do you need to use this class or can you use another one?

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to fix it by further changing the elsarticle class in case any one needs to do it:
first you have to make the title page empty with bringing the footnote with corresponding author by changing the following section:

```
\long\def\MaketitleBox{%
\resetTitleCounters
\def\baselinestretch{1}%
\begin{center}%
\def\baselinestretch{1}%
\Large\@title\par\vskip18pt
\normalsize\elsauthors\par\vskip10pt
\footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt
%  \hrule\vskip12pt
%  \hrule\clearpage
%  \ifvoid\absbox\else\unvbox\absbox\par\vskip10pt\fi
   \printFirstPageNotes
   \ifvoid\absbox\else\clearpage\unvbox\absbox\par\vskip30pt\fi
   \ifvoid\keybox\else\unvbox\keybox\par\vskip10pt\fi
 % \hrule\vskip12pt
\end{center}%
}
```

Afterwards, you have to comment out all rest of commands :

```
 %  \thispagestyle{pprintTitle}%
 %  \printFirstPageNotes
```

This way you will have a title page with corresponding author info on the bottom.